# InnerView not responding to DOM events in its template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Question: when I create the Backbone view inside the scope of another view, the inner view is not responding to DOM events that originate inside its template, however, the outer view is responding to those events. In the example below, the innerview has a submit button, but only the outerview will respond to the click of the submitButton

I'm making a Backbone project that creates a new main view for each route in the Router, and that main view might have subviews for different parts of its page. For example, there's a an `order` route that creates the OrderView page

```
routes: {

            'order': 'orderProduct'
        },

orderProduct: function(){

            this.loadView(new OrderView()); 

        },
```

In the initialize function of OrderView, I create subviews for the OrderView, for example, a formView.

```
 var OrderView = Backbone.View.extend({


        initialize: function(){
            $("body").html(this.el);
            this.template = _.template($('#order-template').html()),

            this.subViews = [];
            var formView = new FormView();
            this.subViews.push(formView);
            this.render();
        },
```

Then in the FormView, I create the obvious, such as a submitButton

```
 var FormView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#forForm',

        initialize: function(){
            this.template = _.template($('#form-template').html());
        },
        events: {
            'click #submitButton' : 'submitForm',
            },

        submitForm: function(){
            ...
        },

        render: function(){

            $('#forForm').append(this.template());
            return this;

        } 
     });
```

The form is rendered to the page, but when I click submit nothing happens. I then added event handler and corresponding function    `'click #submitButton' : 'submitForm',` to the OrderView and it responded to the submit event. So my question is, when I create the FormView inside the scope of the OrderView, why can't the FormView respond to events inside the scope of its template?

FormTemplate

```
   <script type="text/template" id="form-template">
    <button id="submitButton">submit</button>
   </script>
```

Update:

I should note that the dom element where the form-template (rendered by the inner view) is appended is contained in the order-template (the outer view). Even though that's the case, since the events the FormView is responding to originate in clicks inside the form-template (i.e. when submitButton is clicked), I assumed FormView would be able to respond to the events.

```
<script type="text/template" id="order-template">
  <div class="container">

    <div class='row'>

      <div class="col-md-6">



     <div id="forForm">
     </div>



      </div> 
      <div class="col-md-6">

     ...ommitted...

      </div> 

  </div>

  </div>

</script>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean with `I then added event handler`. Isn't it logical that the event needs to be defined before it's triggered? I also don't see any events defined on the parent view (OrderView) so how can this listen to events? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: @KimGysen I didn't define any events originally on the OrderView, however, once I discovered that the FormView wasn't responding to the click of the `submitButton` id (which is in the form-template), I experimented by seeing if the view surrounding the form-template (i.e.OrderView) was responding to the events, and, as I noted in the OP, it was. However, I didn't include that in the code for OrderView because I was just testing, it's not what I want. If an `id` in the form-template is clicked, I want to respond to it in the FormView (which renders the form-template). Clear now?

Comment: @muistooshort I got it to work by using setElement as described in my answer below, though as I explain I'm not sure why it's necessary. I'll try to setup a jsfiddle and post later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, I had to use `setElement` when rendering the FormView from the render function of the OrderView, setting the OrderView container to be the element of the FormView. I don't know why this is necessary. I've seen many Backbone apps that render one view inside another (for example, apps that use separate views for `ul` and each `li` in a list) and that's never seemed necessary

This is the relevant code from the render function of the OrderView

```
        _.each(this.subViews, function(view) {          
            view.setElement( this.$el.find('.orderview-container') ).render().el;           
        }, this);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand the question entirely, but I'll try to answer the question by explaining some logic.

Backbone depends on jquery `on` to register to events that are triggered by the DOM.
That means that the moment you instantiate a Backbone view with its `events: {}`object defined, your view will be able to listen to these events, with the view's `el` as the parent element to where events from all child elements will bubble up.

If the parent view has has an `el` defined that wraps the `el's` defined on the child views, than logically these events will bubble up to the highest parent.
If the parent view also decides to monitor a click event on the same child element as the inner views, then this event will bubble up to the highest parent element, unless you decide to end the propagation from a child view, which you can achieve by calling `$(event.currentTarget).stopPropagation()` from the method that handles the event in the child view.

I hope that this made sense and helps you in resolving the problem.

Comment: First, the OrderView is not a parent of the FormView-there's no inheritance taking place. Both views extend from `Backbone.View.extend({ `. I only call FormView a subview because it (along with several other views) is rendered by OrderView in an element `#forForm` (see update to OP) contained within OrderView's template, i.e. OrderView represents the page at the `order` route, and FormView (which renders form-template) is just one of the small parts of the order page. Since the `id` being clicked is in `form-template`, I expect FormView to be able to respond to it. It can't.

Comment: If my last comment isn't clear, this is not a situation where propogation is happening. The triggered events go directly to OrderView, not to FormView. Is it because the element for form-template (rendered by FormView) is appended is within OrderView's template (at id `forForm`). See update to OP? If so, how can I fix it?

Comment: Hm, the problem is a bit blurry for me. Logically indeed, the inner form can listen to events. Even when using plain jQuery, you can attach an event listener to both the inner element and the outer: both can listen to the same event. So when just defining an events object on the FormView, it should work. Is that what doesn't work for you?

Comment: yes, I define an event on the FormView `'click #submitButton' : 'submitForm',`. That `#submitButton` id is in the `form-template`, which is rendered by FormView. However, I can only respond to the event in OrderView (which renders FormView in the `forForm` id in OrderView's template)

Comment: I made a quick fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/C9wew/6483/. In the fiddle, the elements are already in the DOM instead of rendered templates, but the result should be the same. Is that what you try to achieve?